# Updating mongodb with angularjs and node

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I need to update my mongodb using nodejs and angularjs on the front end. I have the below code but i get error like  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'put' of undefined

**My angularjs controller** :

```
myApp.controller('userController', ['$scope', '$resource', 'AuthService','iden','$http', function ($scope, $resource, AuthService,iden,$http) {

console.log(usersOnline);
var Meetup = $resource('/api/user', {},{
  query: {method: 'get', isArray: true}
});

$scope.users = [];
$scope.userss = [];
$scope.text='mikyas';
  Meetup.query({text: usersOnline}).$promise.then(function (results) {
    $scope.users = results;
  }, function(error) {
  // console.log(error);
   $scope.meetups = [];
});
  console.log(usersOnline);


function getUser(iden,$http) {
//return promise here
  var Users = $resource('/api/users', {},{
  query: {method: 'get', isArray: true}
  });

  $scope.usersOnline='a';
    return Users.query({username: usersOnline}).$promise
    //other code as is

}

$scope.id='cpasgrave';
$scope.lol=getUser();
$scope.lol.then(function(user,$http){
console.log(user[0]._id);
iden=user[0]._id;
 $scope.userss = user;
 console.log(iden);

$http.put('/api/updateUser' + user[0]._id, user[0]);
});
console.log(iden);


}]);
```

And my api on the server side :
*

```
module.exports.updateUser = function (req, res) {
var id = req.body.id;
User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
  if (err) throw err;

  // change the users location
  user.auto = 'true';

  // save the user
  user.save(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log('User successfully updated!');
  });

});
}
`
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `$http` argument in your `$scope.lol.then(function(user,$http)` function.

```
$scope.lol.then(function(user){
  console.log(user[0]._id);
  iden=user[0]._id;
  $scope.userss = user;
  console.log(iden);

  $http.put('/api/updateUser' + user[0]._id, user[0]);
});
```

Also, if you define `getUser (iden, $http)`, make sure you put correct arguments when you call it...

```
$scope.id='cpasgrave';
$scope.lol=getUser(iden, $http);
```

Answer (score 0):

try replacing this:

```
 $http.put('/api/updateUser' + user[0]._id, user[0]);
 });
```

with this:

```
 $http({
    method: 'PUT',
    url: '/api/updateUser' + user[0]._id, user[0]
 }).then(function successCallback(response) {
     console.log('put success');
 }, function errorCallback(response) {
     console.log('put failed');
 });
```